# How to program button in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7

I need help with programming button in visual studio phone. I would like to program it, that when I press button it goes to next page (something like subpage) in application. Should this subpage made as new xaml file ? Or how to make such a subpage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a new `Page` and call `NavigationService.Navigate` in `OnClick` button event handler

Answer (score 0):

For create a new page, click right in your project's folder pages, and select "add new element" , select your type of page windows phone, and after, rename this, add this.

after, in your button ( in your first page ) create an click event :

```
<Button Click="navigate" Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="button1"  />
```

here, my event it's a "click event" and , when user click in the button, the method "navigate" ( in your .cs page) was called

In your .cs, you add this method :

```
private void navigate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new System.Uri("/yourFolderPage/yourNextPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and, it's the end, the event was called the method, the method call your next page, it's over ^^

Hope my explication help you.

Comment: Just click in the arrow before the name of your xaml file! every Xaml file are linked with .cs ( c Sharp ) file.
When you define an event in your test.xaml page ( for example) , the method call by your event are define in the test.cs linked at your test.xaml!